# How to detect coordinate of UISLDER?

Tags: iphone

I am using uislider in my application.Now i want to get position of center button when i am moving slider.How it possible?

Comment: Are you talking about the value of the slider or the actual pixel coordinate of the center button image?

Comment: I am talking about the actual pixel coordinate of the center button image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UISlider *slider = mySlider;
CGRect bounds = slider.bounds;
CGRect trackRect = [slider trackRectForBounds:bounds];
CGRect thumbPosition = [slider thumbRectForBounds:bounds trackRect:trackRect
                                            value:slider.value];
```

See the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISlider/thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:).

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the subviews. However, accessing it like this is prone to breakage in future OS versions. You can probably make a reasonable guess of the coordinates with a little math though.